# Mock functions in a function dict in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

Let's say I have a class declared like below:

```
class SampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.ops = {
           'key 1': self.function_a,
           'key 2': self.function_b
       }

    def function_a(self):
      print('Inside a')

    def function_b(self):
      print('Inside b')

    def main(self, key):
       self.ops[key]()
```

Based on the key I get, I choose and execute either of the 2 functions.

I am trying to unit test main function but I am not able to patch either `function_a` or `function_b`.

I am writing unit tests in a separate file called `test.py`.

When I try to patch function_a with :

```
self.sampleclass = SampleClass()
with patch.object(SampleClass, 'function_a', return_value=None) as test_function:
    self.sampleclass.main('key1')
```

Control goes into `function_a` and `Inside a` is printed.

How does one mock a function that is called from a function dict?

Comment: That example won't work. But if it did, I wouldn't mock methods that were also part of the class under test. They're effectively implementation detail, test them by calling `main` and making sure you get the expected value back from the real method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had missed self keyword before the functions in the function dict. Corrected it now. The code would work now. But I am not able to unit test main function without calling function_a. For me function_a is an API that would need authentication and stuff so I would rather it didn't get called.

Comment: You can mock the things that `function_a` (actually a method) calls in turn; in this case, mocking `print` would be fine. If you're making API requests from it with `requests`, for example, look into the `responses` library. But don't mock out the method itself; the unit is `SampleClass`, not the `main` method alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to patch dictionary entries, here's an example that's very similar to what you posted:

```
from mock import patch, Mock

class SampleClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ops = {
            'key 1': self.function_a,
            'key 2': self.function_b
        }

    def function_a(self):
        print('Inside a')

    def function_b(self):
        print('Inside b')

    def main(self, key):
        self.ops[key]()

test_function = Mock(name='mock_a')

sampleclass = SampleClass()
with patch.dict(sampleclass.ops, {'key 1': test_function}):
    sampleclass.main('key 1')

    test_function.assert_called_once()
```

I think you could also solve your problem by patching `SampleClass` before you create an instance of it.

However, I suggest you consider mocking part of `function_a()` instead of trying to mock the whole thing. That will be easier to understand, and probably put the mock object at a better seam between the system under test and its dependencies.

For example, imagine your `SampleClass` needs mocking, because it logs in to a web service and then sends several requests. If `function_a()` calls `self.login()` before making those requests, then you can just mock `SampleClass.login()`.

```
from mock import patch

class SampleClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ops = {
            'key 1': self.function_a,
            'key 2': self.function_b
        }

    def login(self):
        session = None
        # session = service.login(username, password)
        return session

    def function_a(self):
        session = self.login()
        session.send('Inside a')

    def function_b(self):
        session = self.login()
        session.send('Inside b')

    def main(self, key):
        self.ops[key]()

sampleclass = SampleClass()
with patch('__main__.SampleClass.login') as test_function:
    sampleclass.main('key 1')

    test_function.assert_called_once()
    test_function.return_value.send.assert_called_once_with('Inside a')
```